# Обновление содержимого GoogleMap InfoWindow

Tags: java, android

Использую InfoWindowAdapter

```
private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private View view;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);          
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
         TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        // тут применяю текст контролам, при первом открытии данные не 
         //пременяються 
       //так же запускаю asynctask и передаю туда textView и обновляю данные 
        //этого textView  там 

        return view;
    }
}
```

переопределил метод **OnMarkerClickListener**

```
gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Но при первоначальном открытии InfoWindow данные на нем пустые (дефаултные данные).